# Rewrite rule not working

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page on my wordpresss with url `/sca`. I want all traffic from `/sca/project_0` to direct to `/sca?urn=project_0`. I added a rule to my `.htaccess` file but it is not working. I don't think this a problem with mod_rewrite as permalinks are working. Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sca/([^/]*)$ sca/urn=$1 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`RewriteRule ^sca/* sca?urn=$1 [R=301,L]` is partly working, only that I'm not getting any parameter, it is returning `/sca/project_0` as `/sca?urn=`.

Comment: Note the `sca` vs `src` in your question.

Comment: i've corrected it but it's not the issue

Comment: You need to put it right after the `RewriteBase`  line. The `[L]` flag for the other rules mean "last", Apache will ignore yours where it is at the moment.

Comment: not working,it says page not found

Comment: i've updated the new .htaccess file

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^sca/([^/]*)$ /sca/?urn=$1`, you're most likely missing the ?

Comment: nopes, still not working

Answer (score 1):

If this address already gets traffic (from inbound links etc.) why don't you try a good old fashioned redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /sca/project_0 http://www.yourdomain.com/sca?urn=project_0

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or use the 301 redirect in addition to your rewrite rule:

```
Redirect 301 /sca/project_0 http://www.yourdomain.com/sca?urn=project_0

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sca/([^/]*)$ sca/urn=$1 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also note that WP is often deleting additional rewrite rules inside `#Begin WordPress #End WordPress`. And sometimes rewrite rules do not behave like they should in localhost.

Comment: i'ts not on a localhost

Comment: it's not working

Comment: RewriteRule ^sca/* sca?urn=$1[R=301,L] is partly working, only that i'm not getting any parameter, it is returning /sca/project_0 as /sca?urn=

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 RewriteRule ^sca/([^/]*)$ sca\?urn=$1
```

Comment: nopes, still not working

Comment: RewriteRule ^sca/* sca?urn=$1[R=301,L] is partly working, only that i'm not getting any parameter, it is returning /sca/project_0 as /sca?urn=

Comment: Add  the flag  [QSA] to pass parameters.  I think that will do it.